# Exportar dataTable a PDF y Excel

Tags: php, datatables

Necesito exportar los datos de un dataTable a Excel y PDF pero me surge un Problema. Al querer agregar los botones de exportar Excel y PDF desaparece el selector de número de registros para mostrar porque ese lugar lo pasa a ocupar los botones Excel y PDF y quiero que también se muestre el selector de número de registros para mostrar.

**Librerías utilizadas**

```js
<link href="plugins/datatables/extensions/Responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">


<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables/extensions/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables/extensions/Responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

**Propiedades que tiene la tabla**

```js
<table id="mtable" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Script del dataTable**

```js
<!-- Inicio DataTable -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
      "language":{
       "lengthMenu":"Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página.",
       "zeroRecords": "Lo sentimos. No se encontraron registros.",
             "sInfo": "Mostrando: _START_ de _END_ - Total registros: _TOTAL_ ",
             "infoEmpty": "No hay registros aún.",
             "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
             "search" : "Búsqueda",
             "LoadingRecords": "Cargando ...",
             "Processing": "Procesando...",
             "SearchPlaceholder": "Comience a teclear...",
             "paginate": {
     "previous": "Anterior",
     "next": "Siguiente", 
     }
      }
     });
 } );
</script>
<!-- Fin DataTable -->
```

**Script de los botones excel, PDP, Print**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mtable').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Qué se debe hacer para que también aparezca el select que permite mostrar los registros que uno desee. Y también como hago si no quiero exportar todas las columnas? Y como se puede cambiar el título que sale al exportar los archivos, pues aparece un titulo que no se donde sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de tanto buscar pude conseguir hacer lo que quería y era que me mostrara el buscador y el select de mostrar cantidad de registros y los botones para exportar los datos del dataTable sin perder el selector de registros. La solución fue implementar el siguiente código con las librerías que escribí en la pregunta.

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'print', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ]
} );
  
table.buttons().container()
    .appendTo( $('.col-sm-6:eq(0)', table.table().container() ) );
</script>
```

La última parte es la que permite poder agregar los botones por fuera del div donde se muestra el selector y el buscador del dataTable, quedando de la siguiente manera como se ve la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

te comento que con ese código debería salirte cargarte los botones pero los de flash que son por defecto, te recomiendo que busque los de html5 
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

prueba con lo siguiente

```
 table =  $("element").DataTable({
        buttons:[
            'excelHtml5'
        ],
        dom: 'lBf',
```

Comment: Los botones los muestra, el problema es que los pone encima del select donde se selecciona los registro que quiero ver por página

Comment: Porque le dan un -1 a la respuesta, si es que no así, por lo menos hagan el aporte y no critiquen a alguien que quiere ayudar

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo te sirvio de algo?

Comment: No amigo nada aún. Muestra los botones pero desaparece el select de registros

Comment: con esto que agregue te muestro un ejemplo de los botonos html5 (que son mejor que los que trae por defecto datatable )